# How to replace QGIS featureAtId() with getfeatures()?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to upgrade a script made for QGIS 1.8 to work at version 2.14

One of the problems I face is that the `featureAtId` function at 2.14 is now obsolete. Original codes looks like this.

```
        for feature in coastal_10k_layer.dataProvider().fields():
            coastal_10k_layer.featureAtId(feature, f)
            geo = f.geometry()
            if geo:
                geometry = QgsGeometry(geo) 
                self.geometries_10k.append(geometry)
```

I tried something like this as official site recommended and doesn't work.

```
        for f in coastal_10k_layer.getFeatures():
            geo = f.geometry()
            if geo:
                geometry = QgsGeometry(geo) 
                self.geometries_10k.append(geometry)
```

Is there any way to do this?